# ASP.net Validation for RadioButton

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want validation like, if i select Status as Reject then there must be some Comments(compulsory). and if status is Accept then comments may be blank (not compulsory)

[image]

How I will do it in ASP.NET, Please find my code

```
 <tr> 
                        <td width="30%">
                            <b>Status:</b> 
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="lAccept" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                CausesValidation="True" Text="Accept" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="lReject" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                CausesValidation="True" Text="Reject " />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Please Select it is Accepted or Rejected" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td width="30%">
                            <b>Qty Rejected:</b> 
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="lRejectedQty" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            <%--  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Only interger between 1 to 10000000 " ondisposed="Page_Load" 
                                oninit="Page_Load" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>--%>
                            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator3" runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Rejected Quantity must be in change of 1 to 10,000,000" 
                                ControlToValidate="lRejectedQty" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" 
                                MaximumValue="10000000" MinimumValue="1"></asp:RangeValidator>

                        </td>   

                    </tr> 
                    <tr> <td width="30%">
                            <b>Comments:</b> 
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <TEXTAREA rows=5 cols=40  name="lComments" id="lComments"></TEXTAREA>
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for this is to use a `CustomValidator`.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="You must enter Comments if you choose to Reject."
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Then in your code-behind you may do more detailed checks for it being valid or not

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = true; // set it to be valid by default

    if (lReject.Checked == true && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lComments.Text) == true)
    {
        // Reject was selected and no comments were entered
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

The drawback is that this requires a *PostBack* to the server and will validate after the other types in most cases.